# Finding an expression for $f^{-1}$ (function)

Tags: functions

I need help with part (a) of this problem.

Two functions, f and g are defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{ x +1 }$ and $g(x) = mx+c$

(a)  Find an expression for $f^{-1}$

I don't know how to make $x$ the subject in this case, or if that's what you're suppose to do by equating it with $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that we want to try and find the value of $x$ for a particular value of $f(x)$. So we let $y=f(x)$ and solve for $x$. In this case we have
$$\begin{align}&y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}=1-\frac{2}{x+1}\\\implies& y-1=-\frac{2}{x+1}\\\implies &x+1=-\frac{2}{y-1}\\\implies& x=-\frac{2}{y-1}-1=\frac{-y-1}{y-1}=\frac{y+1}{1-y}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $y=f^{-1}(x)$. Solve for $y$ in $x=\displaystyle\frac{y-1}{y+1}.$

Answer (score 0):

First let $y=f(x)$ so we have $$y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}\\
y(x+1)=x-1\\
xy+y=x-1\\
xy-x=-1-y\\
x(y-1)=-1-y\\
x=\frac{-1-y}{y-1}\\
x=\frac{1+y}{1-y}$$

Hence $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$

It is also good show the domain of the function $f^{-1}$ as well. Clearly $x\neq1$ or there'd be a divide zero error.